# "Data must be aligned to block boundary in ECB mode" trying to encrypt and decrypt in lambda using python3.6

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt a set of data that i am getting from api event.

```
Payload (unencrypted):
{"data": {"loan_number":"BAS123JKE"},"checksum":
"4406f3578082e33d1b16c0a7da74d2eb921eab48"}

Payload (encrypted):
VAsuXX7Pjs6G5PDQwteWsUkM0B5Zv94UFKqFe5tZLdRZYaBKFMU8e7r1YGpy3TgC7yu0R8FL
a9+Iy3H05xQ21Fgg1bZNMwpe7osoNu19BqKN5R4CHDeWjTT7nn0lcQQwm+LsHNW2+FXa5
wcpn5aD1w==
```

Here is my below code which is not accurate.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad
if "checksum" in item:
        item = str(item)
        print(item)
        item = item.encode('utf8')
        message = cipher.encrypt(item)
        print(message.hex())
else:
    item = item.encode("utf8")
    decipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
    msg_dec = decipher.decrypt(item)
    print(unpad(msg_dec, BLOCK_SIZE))
```

here is my event which is taking encrypted data

```
"body":"VAsuXX7Pjs6G5PDQwteWsUkM0B5Zv94UFKqFe5tZLdRZYaBKFMU8e7r1YGpy3TgC7yu0R8FLa9+Iy3H05xQ21Fgg1bZNMwpe7osoNu19BqKN5R4CHDeWjTT7nn0lcQQwm+LsHNW2+FXa5wcpn5aD1w==",
```

here is my error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Data must be aligned to block boundary in ECB mode",
  "errorType": "ValueError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/billFetch.py",
      31,
      "lambda_handler",
      "msg_dec = decipher.decrypt(item)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/Crypto/Cipher/_mode_ecb.py",
      196,
      "decrypt",
      "raise ValueError(\"Data must be aligned to block boundary in ECB mode\")"
    ]
  ]
}
```

What can i do to get rid of an error?

Answer (score 1):

You include the "pad" function in your import section but do **not** pad the data on encryption side.

Below you find a full example code that runs an encryption and decryption with a string. It uses the **PyCryptoDome** library for the encryption part.

**Security warning**: the usage of AES in **ECB mode** is **UNSECURE** and highly discouraged.

This is a sample output:

```
AES ECB 256 String encryption with random key full
plaintext: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
encryptionKey (Base64): 3eXNU969rlNGp/zpTjGKpjOhp380P6dOOUhGqZzcDIU=

* * * Encryption * * *
ciphertext: QUX/s46vCxhfugLkREW0h2LPzeNrx/Tz8JVJDYtPrIzHktu10MKTzi+0OHWF+dZm
output is (Base64) ciphertext

* * * Decryption * * *
decryptionKey (Base64): 3eXNU969rlNGp/zpTjGKpjOhp380P6dOOUhGqZzcDIU=
ciphertext (Base64): QUX/s46vCxhfugLkREW0h2LPzeNrx/Tz8JVJDYtPrIzHktu10MKTzi+0OHWF+dZm
input is (Base64) ciphertext
plaintext:  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad
from Crypto.Util.Padding import unpad
import base64

def base64Encoding(input):
  dataBase64 = base64.b64encode(input)
  dataBase64P = dataBase64.decode("UTF-8")
  return dataBase64P

def base64Decoding(input):
    return base64.decodebytes(input.encode("ascii"))

def generateRandomAesKey():
  return get_random_bytes(32)

def aesEcbEncryptToBase64(encryptionKey, plaintext):
  cipher = AES.new(encryptionKey, AES.MODE_ECB)
  ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(pad(plaintext.encode("ascii"), AES.block_size))
  ciphertextBase64 = base64Encoding(ciphertext)
  return ciphertextBase64

def aesEcbDecryptFromBase64(decryptionKey, ciphertextDecryptionBase64):
  ciphertext = base64Decoding(ciphertextDecryptionBase64)
  cipher = AES.new(decryptionKey, AES.MODE_ECB)
  decryptedtext = unpad(cipher.decrypt(ciphertext), AES.block_size)
  decryptedtextP = decryptedtext.decode("UTF-8")
  return decryptedtextP
  
print("AES ECB 256 String encryption with random key full")

plaintext = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
print("plaintext: " + plaintext)

encryptionKey = generateRandomAesKey()
encryptionKeyBase64 = base64Encoding(encryptionKey)
print("encryptionKey (Base64): " + encryptionKeyBase64)

print("\n* * * Encryption * * *") 
ciphertextBase64 = aesEcbEncryptToBase64(encryptionKey, plaintext)
print("ciphertext: " + ciphertextBase64)
print("output is (Base64) ciphertext")

print("\n* * * Decryption * * *") 
ciphertextDecryptionBase64 = ciphertextBase64
decryptionKeyBase64 = encryptionKeyBase64
decryptionKey = base64Decoding(decryptionKeyBase64)
print("decryptionKey (Base64): " + decryptionKeyBase64)
print("ciphertext (Base64): " + ciphertextDecryptionBase64)
print("input is (Base64) ciphertext")
decryptedtext = aesEcbDecryptFromBase64(decryptionKey, ciphertextBase64)
print("plaintext:  " + decryptedtext)
```